# How to enable the item menu in a SharePoint 2013 list?

Tags: list, list-view, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint list and normally the 'three points' (item menu with the options View Item etc.) are always a column. I don't know why but this is not the case in my view/list. How can I change it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use Title column then you can add that menu to your another existing column also.

1.Open your View page( default AllItems.aspx) in designer(list and Libraries -> List_name -> Views -> AllItems.aspx).

2. Now Look for `FieldRef` tag of your item to which you want to attach that menu.
3. Now add `ListItemMenu="TRUE"` in that tag.
4. Save youe page and its done.

Answer (score 5):

- Open List > From above ribbon at List tab > Select modify view

[image]

- Make sure that this column (  `Title (linked to item with edit menu)`  ) is selected at your view.

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys very much. I saw that the (linked to item with edit menu) is standing behind another column. I may accidentally changed it. How can I change it back?

Comment: How is it standing behind ? should you share any screen shot or elaborate more, please ?

Comment: Sorry my English isn't perfect, thought it was clear. I have two columns (title and comment). How it should be: Title (linked to item with edit menu) | Comment       How it looks like in my settings: Title | Comment (linked to item with edit menu)

Hope you understand what I mean!

Comment: you need to merge both items to be one column and linked to edit item , or you need title linked to edit and comment linked to another page that is setting ?

Comment: No, I just want the title to be linked to the edit item menu. The other column shouldn't be linked to anything.

Answer (score 4):

Modify the view and make sure that the column called Title (with Edit Menu) is selected.  This is the one that has the dropdown menu attached to it.

Comment: Thank you guys very much. I saw that the (linked to item with edit menu) is standing behind another column. I may accidentally changed it. How can I change it back?

Comment: I don't want you to have to double post each response.  M.Qassas took the time to provide you a screenshot, so let's just continue in his answer thread below and upvote that.  (I agree with his latest comment; we need to know what "standing behind another column" means.  Provide a screenshot if you can, it's easier than trying to describe with words.)